# Dual boot using BIOS with caddy not working while with other hdd

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, multi-boot

I have a two systems at my Laptop 5742 Acer:

1. Windows 7 at caddy ssd 128Gb instead CD-ROM.
2. Ubuntu at sshd 1Gb inside sata port laptop (standard place).

I want to have dual boot using BIOS boot menu.The Problem is when I have both at the same time in laptop, there is only 1Gb sshd visible in bios and at boot menu.
If I remove 1Gb sshd from laptop ssh 128Gb at caddy place boots corectly.

I update and unlock bios and still it doesn't work.
How to make boot menu for both?